# Ошибка в авто-тесте selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Начинаю писать автоматические тесты, один из них не исполняется. Проблема в последних 2 строчках, так как без них все работает. Пробовал поиск и по селектору, классу и id.

```
@Test
public void firsTest() {
    java.lang.String someSearchString = "something";

    driver.get("http://rozetka.com.ua/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.className("header-search-input-text")).sendKeys(someSearchString);
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn-link-i")).click();

    java.lang.String searchResult = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".g-i-tile-i-title.clearfix>a")).getText();

    Assert.assertEquals(searchResult, someSearchString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня с вашим кодом searchResult = "Зажигалка Zippo Something Patriotic (20895)" что <>"something". Текст не совпадает и assertEquals возвращает false. Вы правильно находите элементы, но текст того что найдено и того что ищется не равны.Или я не понял суть вопроса?